# Drums and wave equation, a clarification of an assertion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have read somewhere something that sounds like that:

'Given the shape of a drum , thanks to well-known formulas, we can deduce all its vibration frequencies and so the sound that it is capable to produce'

My question is this:

since there are almost no regions of the plane for which we can solve explicitly the wave equation ( then I obtain  an eigenvalue problem), is this assertion true or expressed correctly? Is this the meaning of this phrase?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Marc Kac wrote a famous paper called "Can one hear the shape of a drum?" https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/ACHA.READ.F03/kac-drum.pdf. Have a look at that.